# In Python, what's difference between some_string.lower() and str.lower(some_string)

Tags: python, methods, built-in

I am confused with built-in method in Python.
For instance, what is the `some_string.lower()` and `str.lower(some_string)` and how are they different?

Answer (score 10):

`str` is the name of the class of all strings in Python. `str.lower` is one of its methods.

If you call `lower` on one of its instances (e.g. `'ABC'.lower()`), you call a **bound method**, which automatically sends the called object as the first argument (usually called `self`).

If you call `lower` on the class itself (i.e. you use `str.lower()`), then you call an **unbound method**, which doesn't provide the self argument automatically. Therefore, you have to specify the object to act upon by yourself.

If all of this seems hard to understand, it will be easier when you consider how methods are defined in the classes. Let's say we create our own very simple class, which represents a point (X,Y coordinate in space). And has a `show()` method to print the point.

```
class Point:
    """This is the constructor of Point"""
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        # Save arguments as field of our class instance (self)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def show(self):
        print self.x, self.y

# We now create an instance of Point:
p = Point(1.0, 2.0)

# We now show p by calling a bound method
p.show()
```

Note that we didn't have to specify the self argument (so p.show() was called with no arguments). In reality, the previous call was more or less equivalent to this:

```
Point.show(p)
```

They're not entirely equivalent, but that's a more advanced topic. One of the simplest cases when they will not be equivalent is if you change the value of p.show after creating the object, for instance:

```
p.show = 4
```

Now, `p.show()` won't even compile, since p.show is not a function anymore, but an integer! However, `Point.show(p)` would still be unchanged, since we only modified the `show` attribute in the class instance (`p`) and not in the class itself (`Point`).

Answer (score 3):

The first is a bound method call and the second is an unbound method call.

Think about how you'd write a method like this:

```
class str:
    ...
    def lower(self):
        # And so on
```

The first argument is self. If you use this method from an instance (e.g. `some_string.lower()`, the instance automatically gets passed as the first argument to the method (as `self`).

However, if you call it from the class (as an unbound method), e..g `str.lower(some_string)`, there is no instance to automatically pass as the first argument. So, instead, `some_string` gets passed as self and whatever would've been done with the instance in the first case gets done with `some_string`.

It's never really necessary to use the unbound version, however, as any string will have a `lower()` method that you can call. The preferred style is to use `some_string.lower()`.

Comment: This answer is misleading or imcomplete. The two are really the same (although `obj.method` gives you a thin "bound method" wrapper while `cls.method` gives you just the function or a "unbound method" wrapper that does even less than the "bound method" wrapper). And "class method" generally refers to a method that can *only* be called on the class and doesn't necessarily take an instance of the same class as first parameter.

Comment: @delnan yeah, you're right. I'm going to rework my answer a bit.

Comment: delnan's right. And it even gets more complicated, since besides class methods and instance methods (bound and unbounnd) there are both static methods and class methods. Static methods are just like regular functions that are members of the class and they can take any first argument (or non at all). Class methods, on the other hand, are methods that take an implicit cls argument which is the class type itself. So they are like bound methods, only they are not bound to an instance, but rather to a class.